# Google Maps API RadarSearch not working for London

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

If I go to the following location:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.5112139,-0.1198244&types=lodging&radius=3200&sensor=false&key=yourKey
```

I get the error:

```
{
    "debug_info" : [],
    "html_attributions" : [],
    "results" : [],
    "status" : "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
}
```

Is there any reason for this?

When I lookup Bristol(`51.454513,-2.58791`), Ipswitch(`52.056736,1.14822`) or Edinburgh(`55.953252,-3.188267`) I get a normal JSON file back full of data.

Comment: How can we tell you this when the reason is also unknown to google(you may report a bug). However, with a smaller radius, e.g. 1500 I get results.

Comment: The Radar Search is only meant to return the top 200 properties.  Probably your radius of 3200m should be reduced if you're searching for 'lodgings' in somewhere like central London (although that doesn't explain the bug; it [should allow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests) you to search up to 50km)

Comment: I know. may be if it has to many results to return it just doesn't return any results so it gives you a chance to be more specfic

Comment: where can I get the key from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how Google works internally.

Unknown error simply means to me that "We have an error with your request, and we don't want you to know what the exact error is". Most of time, it is from the internal exception handling process.

Honestly, I don't know what happens in Google.

However, if you change your radius from 3500 meter to 2000 meter, it works fine

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.5112139,-0.11982439999997041&types=lodging&radius=2100&sensor=false&key=key

My guess is there are too many results, and Google cannot handle that much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but the URL works sometimes, and sometimes doesn't work.
The "UNKNOWN_ERROR" status may be internal error of Google.

To prevent the error temporally, shorten the radius.
And report this to the gmaps-issues-tracker.
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/

Answer (score 1):

Rank by distance seems to have some issues with radius. Is this implied in your situation?

[Google](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5892&q=radius&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal)

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230140/must-be-a-bug-in-google-places-api)